# Magento 2 Edit wishlist modal footer

Tags: magento2, edit, modal-popup, modal

The site I'm working on has changed the wishlist popup to a free samples popup.

I'm trying to edit the modal footer but I cannot find a template for it.

The developer before me has created a module to edit the content of the popup, but the footer and header is not included.

Is there another way around editing this modal popup?

Comment: You can check it by enabling template path hints from Magento admin.

Comment: I have tried but it only gives me the template for the content which I already have

Comment: The modal header and footer are defined using knockout so you can find the code within the static content under magento_wishlist this should give you an idea of were the content is being set

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can override the template, but if you do it will change for all modal/pop up being triggered in your site. (Footer is not a different template, modals are a complete set of HTML per type)

You have two options:

1. Override directly the modal templating from `Magento_Ui` -> `vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/modal` folder has all the templates for every option of the modal, including header, wrapper and footer. You will need to override these templates on your theme (your custom theme under `app/frontend`) dir keeping same path structure, deploy and you will see your new changes. Like I said before, this will change all the modal templates across the site, not only the one you "need" to.
2. Extend the modal widget and create your own call to your new template path. This one is more complicated if you are not experienced with how Magento 2 development fallback works. For instance you will need to create your new widget for the new modal within your module, call the modal widget and extend it, change on the require path for a new template (depending on which type you want to change properly) and change the function `_renderModal` within your widget to call for the new template.

To give you the whole answer for the second option will take a lot, and requires for you to read more about how Magento development works and be familiar with it. More information check: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html#extend_js_widget

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first find the js which trigger this modal popup and then you can modify the popup

> Like you can remove footer

```
var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                title: 'Customer Details',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }],
                opened: function($Event) {
                    $(".modal-footer").hide();
                }
            };
```

You can also check this Magento devdoc link for more options 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Comment: If you hide the footer, you won't have CTA's buttons. Not the ideal solution for the question.

Comment: its just example that you can hide the footer same you can edit the button text etc

Comment: Those parameters are the only thing you can change of the templating through the widget. We are on the same page with that for sure. The question asks to a change of the template structure, so, for this case, the need is to override templating or creating a new one for a extend of the widget under your current theme